# ODBC configuration

Tags: odbc, data-synchronization

I have an internal system which includes a Database and I'm also using QuickBooks Accounting package. Is there anyway I can sync my Quickbooks database with my internal system database? What I want to accomplish is to enter records on Quickbooks and at the end of the day those records to be synced to my other database. Is this possible? I have heard of ODBC but does not know how it works. Can someone advice please? If Im able to sync the two databases, would the two databases need to be identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ODBC Support for QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions](http://enterprisesuite.intuit.com/support/odbc.jsp)

> Intuit Developer Network member FLEXQuarters to provide a read-only ODBC driver, called QODBC, for use with your QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions software. The QODBC driver (located at File >> Utilities >> Setup QODBC) allows administrator access to your QuickBooks data using 3rd party applications such as Microsoft Excel or Access or Crystal Reports.

We tried to use ODBC for QB few years ago but gave up on this idea because it was painfully slow! So our developers created an extract application using QB API to export the data we need out of the QB to a CSV file which we import into a table on our SQL Server. This process have it's own drawbacks like when a QB client gets updated to a newer version everybody needs to get on the same version otherwise the export application fails.

Again, we developed this few years ago and tested with, perhaps, an old ODBC driver. Also have only handful of QB clients that need to be maintained. This has been working for us all these years.

Here is a good starting point if you'd like to start developing an application using QB SDK -- [QuickBooks Desktop](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb)

HTH

Comment: Thanks. Is the API you developed available for sale?

Comment: @ry12, our developers used QB API to write an extract program. I edited my answer with a good starting point!